# QSqlQuery does not prepare sql for PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt

I'm trying to prepare sql query with `QSqlQuery`, but for every sql i'm getting an error about `EXECUTE` syntax.

Here I'm connecting to database:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("test_db");
db.setUserName("postgres");

if (!db.open())
{
    qWarning() << "DB not opened";
    return;
}
```

And here preparing sql:

```
QString str { "INSERT INTO :table (test_text, test_int) VALUES (:txt, :int)" };

QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare(str);
query.bindValue(":table", "test_table");
query.bindValue(":txt", "test");
query.bindValue(":int", 1);
```

Then I execute prepared query

```
if (!query.exec())
{
    qWarning() << query.lastError();
} else {
    qWarning() << "success!";
}
```

And an error occurs:

> **QSqlError("42601", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "ERROR:  syntax error at or near: \"(\")\nLine 1: EXECUTE  ('test_table', NULL, NULL)\n                   ^\n(42601)"**

But next code works:

```
query.exec(QStringLiteral("INSERT INTO %1 (test_text, test_int) VALUES (%2, %3)").arg("test_table").arg("'test'").arg(1))
```

I used to work with MySQL and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a placeholder for the table name. Also you should check for the return value of QSqlQuery::prepare()